# Google Image search weird issue

Tags: javascript, image, search

Im trying to do a google search by image url using this link, it works for most websites(?), but not all

```
window.open("https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=" + image_url), 'popUpGoogle', 'height=400, width=600, left=10, top=1');
```

Here's the issue, lets take this picture for example
https://vladimirkhil.com/siserver/3/packages/0t%2BefNNidBXgG1am3LaK5nczmak%3D_kLhfz3q9duZyqOT%27x9qDZw%3D%3D/Images/quake.jpg

the link would be

> https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=https://vladimirkhil.com/siserver/3/packages/0t%2BefNNidBXgG1am3LaK5nczmak%3D_kLhfz3q9duZyqOT%27x9qDZw%3D%3D/Images/quake.jpg

But when I open it I get :

> The URL doesn't refer to an image or the image is not publicly accessible.

However, **if I open the image in a new tab, and then do a google search manually by right clicking it works, but whats more weird is that it also works if I go to a "Search by Image" on google and past the exact same image link there**

Any ideas what this could be related to? The URL clearly refers to an image and it is publicly accessible, is it something with the URL encoding? It looks fine to me, also it works in 2nd method that I described so I'm really lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to encode the url if you pass it as argument to another url.

Your base url is:
`https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=`

Your argument url is
`https://vladimirkhil.com/siserver/3/packages/0t%2BefNNidBXgG1am3LaK5nczmak%3D_kLhfz3q9duZyqOT%27x9qDZw%3D%3D/Images/quake.jpg`

Your encoded (encodeURI, escapes '%' signs) argument url is
`https://vladimirkhil.com/siserver/3/packages/0t%252BefNNidBXgG1am3LaK5nczmak%253D_kLhfz3q9duZyqOT%2527x9qDZw%253D%253D/Images/quake.jpg`

Your encoded (encodeURIComponent, escapes '%' and '/' in your case) argument url is
`https%3A%2F%2Fvladimirkhil.com%2Fsiserver%2F3%2Fpackages%2F0t%252BefNNidBXgG1am3LaK5nczmak%253D_kLhfz3q9duZyqOT%2527x9qDZw%253D%253D%2FImages%2Fquake.jpg`

To actually do the encode call the javascript function `encodeURI` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) with the url to encode. The encoding process will escape chars that have a special function in urls (like the % sign in your case)

Your final search url should look like this
`https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=https://vladimirkhil.com/siserver/3/packages/0t%252BefNNidBXgG1am3LaK5nczmak%253D_kLhfz3q9duZyqOT%2527x9qDZw%253D%253D/Images/quake.jpg`

Tested. And worked. At least for me :)

EDIT:
Might be a better option to use `encodeURIComponent` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) over `encodeURI`

Comment: Thank you so much, it works, I see it added plenty of %25's, it seems like the % symbol needed to be encoded right ? But little side note In my link there's %27 for examle, the ' symbol, it was encoded automatically when I pasted the link , so in your link its %2527 (kinda double encoded?), which should be just %27 (still works both ways)
Did i get it right ?

Comment: @maegane62 correct. `%` needs to be encoded because it is used to escape chars in urls and by encoding it, you tell the browser that this one is *not* used to escape something, its just a '%'. `%25` is the encoded url string for '%', verify by decoding it with `decodeURI('%25')` which results in '%'. and the double encoding is also true, the website that is receiving the (encoded) url should decode the parameters before processing. that way, google receives the link you encoded, decodes it once and that way restores the original url like you posted it here